# Passing the API into scope array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I got my API seen below.
 How can I pass it into scope like this?
   I am trying to pass the JSON data into an array like below, but only pass in symbols. Is it achievable ?

```
$scope.sellers = ["12312", "2324", "B23244", "2322en"]


[
  {
    "id": "59a7ef64053bfcf561d6bde0",
    "symbol": "12121",
    "clearingVenue": null,
    "description": "testing",
    "address": "6/9-13 smith St",
    "startAt": null,
    "endAt": null,
    "city": "north",
    "auctionDate": 1504137600000,
    "term": "M",
    "state": "Australia",
    "zipCode": "2334",
    "country": "Australia",
    "relatedSymbols": ["foo"],
    "showUser": true
  }
]
```

my API code

```
this.fetchContracts = function () {
  var date = new Date().toISOString();

   $http.get('/api/contracts', {params: {auctionDate: date}})
        .success(function (result) {
            result && result.length && ($scope.contracts = result);
        });
};
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want... please be more specific

Comment: what I wanna do is passing the JSON data.symbol into an array.

Answer (score 1):

So if you only want to get an arrays of symbols you could to something like this:

```
 $http.get('/api/contracts', {
         params: {
             auctionDate: date
         }
     })
     .success(function (result) {
         result.map(function(v) {
             $scope.yourarray.push(v.symbol)
         })
     });
```

explanation:

once you got the result array from the API, we iterate over it. The result from the API is an array of objects. so we grab the value of "symbols" from each recived object and push it to a new array "yourarray"

Comment: ES5 example, please? Lol, haven't got to 6 yet

Comment: i changed it, look at the map function on mdn:
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map